# How to have future 5 days in my date array using Swift NSDate by canceling every sunday

Tags: swift, nsdate

I was trying to create UIPickerView which let user to select Auction Date for 5 day.But,by my requirements,I need to disable/hide/not add day that are concern with "Sunday".What I mean was if today was 8/7/2015,the data in my UIPickerView will be

```
["All","08/07/2015 (Wed)","09/07/2015 (Thu)","10/07/2015 (Fri)", "11/07/2015 (Sat)","13/07/2015 (Mon)"]
```

As you see,I hide Sunday in that category.And I tried finding the way,but still wrong error..Any help with that please?

Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    var now = NSDate()

    var auctionDate = [String]()

    var sdfDDMMYYYYEEE = NSDateFormatter()
    sdfDDMMYYYYEEE.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy (EEE)"

    var sdfDDMMYYYY = NSDateFormatter()
    sdfDDMMYYYY.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

    var sdfEEE = NSDateFormatter()
    sdfEEE.dateFormat = "EEE"

    // This is how i
    var startTime : NSTimeInterval = (floor(now.timeIntervalSince1970)) + 86400000
    auctionDate.append("All")
    for var i = 0; i < 5; i++ {
        if sdfEEE.stringFromDate(now) == "Sun" {
            now = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(startTime)
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        auctionDate.append(sdfDDMMYYYYEEE.stringFromDate(now) as String)
        now = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(startTime)
    }

    println(auctionDate)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

And I am getting that output in my console

```
[All, 07/07/2015 (Tue), 07/01/2112 (Thu), 08/04/2160 (Tue), 09/07/2208 (Sat), 09/10/2256 (Thu)]
```

Any Help,Please.I am stuck at this problem for so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.

- `NSDate()` and `NSTimeInterval()` work with *seconds*, not milliseconds. 86400000 seconds are (approximately) 1000 days.
- Even adding 86400 seconds is the wrong approach, because a day may
  have 23 or 25 hours in regions with Daylight Saving Time.
- In `now = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(startTime)`, you add the number
  of (milli)seconds to the current date which makes not sense at all.
- Comparing the weekday name against "Sun" will not work in most 
  languages.

Having said all that, here is a possible solution, using the proper
`NSCalendar` methods. With the embedded comments it should be
self-explaining:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
fmt.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy (EEE)"

// Start with today (at midnight):
var date = cal.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())

var auctionDates = [ "All" ]

// Repeat until there are enough dates in the array:
while auctionDates.count < 6 {

    // Compute weekday of date (1 == Sunday)
    let weekDay = cal.component(.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: date)

    // Add to array if not Sunday:
    if weekDay != 1 {
        auctionDates.append(fmt.stringFromDate(date))
    }

    // Advance one day:
    date = cal.dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: 1, toDate: date, options: nil)!
}

println(auctionDates)
```

Comment: Thanks for brilliant answer.Sorry about my error in my code.I am new to swift.

Comment: Can i ask u a question?Is there anyway that I can set my current date to yesterday?